# Windows Authentication Error: Some or all identity references could not be translated

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-authentication

On one of the new VMs I have added to a new domain I have created, I am getting the following error when trying to use impersonation in a WCF service.

```
Unhandled Exception:
   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: 
   Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

The same works on another machine. Any idea on what could be wrong here? Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- the time on the new VM also the time zone, is the VM time in sync?
- did you restart the VM after adding it to the domain?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your Central Administration's Admin account got corrupted (KB934838).

Used the command:

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin DomainName\UserName -password NewPassword
```